# Rounding all Numbers in Database table

Tags: sql, rounding

I need to round all the numbers in a column of a table to 2 decimal places (ie i need 2.109999 to become 2.11)

What is the best way to achieve this? (It only needs to be done as a one off operation)

I am using sql server 2008 R2

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175003.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
UPDATE table SET column = ROUND(column, 2)
```

If you need to modify numbers permanently. Otherwise:

```
SELECT ROUND(column, 2) FROM table
```

To keep existing values in place.

Answer (score 0):

from google: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175003.aspx

```
select round(foo, 2);
```

Though this is only a guess..

Comment: It shouldn't be a guess. A guess is that the OP is too lazy to google.

Comment: @t3hn00b I provided the link to the microsoft page, but the microsoft webpage was not specific enough so it was my best educated guess.